# How to list active applications with PID?

Tags: android, pid

I didn't find answer here, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : mgr.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {
    Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(processInfo.pid)+" "+processInfo.processName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```